# Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator does not exist, but exists egulias/email-validator/src/EmailValidator.php

Tags: laravel, email, composer-php

Laravel is trying to include this file `Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator`, but this file doesn't exists `Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator`. But exists `egulias/email-validator/src/EmailValidator.php`. How can i solve this Problem?

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
         .........................
        "egulias/email-validator": "~2.0",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.0",
         .........................  
    },
```

Error

````
local.ERROR: Class Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator does not exist {"userId":68,"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Egulias\\EmailValidator\\EmailValidator does not exist at /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php:325)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(325): ReflectionClass->__construct('Egulias\\\\EmailVa...')
#1 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(339): Swift_DependencyContainer->createNewInstance('email.validator')
#2 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(115): Swift_DependencyContainer->createSharedInstance('email.validator')
#3 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(385): Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup('email.validator')
#4 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(362): Swift_DependencyContainer->lookupRecursive('email.validator')
#5 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(132): Swift_DependencyContainer->resolveArgs(Array)
#6 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(328): Swift_DependencyContainer->createDependenciesFor('mime.headerfact...')
#7 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(113): Swift_DependencyContainer->createNewInstance('mime.headerfact...')
#8 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(385): Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup('mime.headerfact...')
#9 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(362): Swift_DependencyContainer->lookupRecursive('mime.headerfact...')
#10 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(132): Swift_DependencyContainer->resolveArgs(Array)
#11 /var/www/projectTest/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php(328): Swift_DependencyContainer->createDependenciesFor('mime.headerset') ```
````

Comment: what are your steps to get to the errors?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond  i want to send an email. bevor it worked, but after composer-update it was broken

Comment: Please share more details, like the code triggering the problem

Comment: oh then you may have to find your old composer.json and revert some of the config back.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond how can i do this?

Comment: if you use git, look at the older version, otherwise it's probably lost.

Comment: Please share the **code** triggering the problem, not only the stacktrace